# Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to: State 'frameworks'' is already defined registerState@http://localhost:3030

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a program using the MEAN stack. The server is in express, the front end uses Angular and HTML5 and I am using Bootstrap.  I am interpreting this as saying that "frameworks" is a reserved word.  Is that the problem?   I checked reserved words and could not find that "frameworks" was a reserved.  In addition I have used the word, "frameworks" in other applications.  If you know how to interpret this error and know what I need to fix the program please let me know.

Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
State 'frameworks'' is already defined
registerState@http://localhost:3030

Comment: I only have one file with config but it is quite large.

Comment: Per the Issue description, "You have multiple files that contains a config function to configure your module, like this:", not sure if this is the problem or not.   I only have one file with config but it is quite large and uses the ui-router.  the statement has multiple states and each state has 6 sections.  Could that be my problem?